# Plotting a data set

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, color

I have data set like this (x , y , n) n is the number from 0 to 12 I want to plot this data set but I want to the color of each point be base on the third column. For example if I have 0 in third column get red point on my graph and for 2  get blue and so far.

Comment: it is not very clear to me what sort of list you have. is `x` a list and `y` a list and `n` just a number? or do you have a list of three lists? can you provide some data explicitly?

Comment: I have a coordinate (x,y) which each coordinate is tagged with a number (between 0-12) I want to plot all of those points but for each point have different color depend on the number in third column.

Comment: hi again. I attempted something. if you don't find it helpful, let me know and I will remove the answer

Comment: This may work `GathetBy[data,Last]` and plot the new data set.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your data consist of triplets: {x,y,color}. For an example, we create some data:

```
SeedRandom[10];
dat = RandomInteger[{0, 12}, {20, 3}];
```

We use ListPlot to display the data and color the points using ColorFunction. As ColorFunction only receive {x,y}, we need to look up the third element of the triple:

```
SeedRandom[10];
dat = RandomInteger[{0, 12}, {20, 3}];
ListPlot[dat[[All, 1 ;; 2]], 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[Cases[N@dat, {#1, #2, _}][[1, 3]]/12] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The data points in the x- and y-axes.

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
y = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Create the list to be plotted

```
z = Thread[{x, y}]
```

One way:

```
ListPlot[{#} & /@ z, PlotStyle -> list2]
```

A second way:

```
ListPlot[{{Style[z[[1]], Green]}, {Style[z[[2]], Purple]}, {Style[
    z[[3]], Red]}}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]]
```

A third way:

```
Graphics[Prepend[Riffle[list2, Point /@ list1], PointSize[0.03]], 
 Frame -> True]
```